# Config ObjectMapper to use fields instead of Setter while Deserializing

Tags: java, json, jackson

Java Model:

```
@lombok.Data
public class Foo {
  ...
  private boolean isDefault;
}
```

Serialized to JSON:

```
{
  ...,
  "isDefault" : true
}
```

`ObjectMapper` configuration:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
VisibilityChecker<?> vc = objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
    .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
    .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
    .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
    .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
    .withIsGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
mapper.setVisibility(vc);
```

Question: the code cannot deserialize the JSON to java object and fails with `UnrecognizedPropertyException` for `isDefault` even though it perfectly serializes it to JSON. Any thought?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a getter for isDefault in the model ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with jackson. This is basic java lang specification. no external object can read a private instance variable of another without a public getter method (not without reflection)

Comment: Please note: `@Data`

Comment: One thing which is probably not the problem per se is the naming. Your property has name which sounds like a getter already. Usually you would have property `default` and getter `isDefault`. Again, I doubt this is the problem but I would at least try to name it so it's less confusing for both people and the tool.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I think you just forgot for a moment that `default` is a keyword :)
Nevertheless, changing the name is not an option.